# Event wiring with mef

Tags: c#, events, mef

Can anyone help me with this problem? I'm working with the MEF framework, but I would like to communicate via events with "the module" to the plugin.

I've created a shared interface between those two parts this

```
public class BaseModule 
{          
    public event EventHandler<FeedBackArguments> SendFeedBack;
    public event EventHandler<ResultArguments> SendResult;


    public void InvokeFeedback(string message) {

        if (SendFeedBack != null)
            SendFeedBack(this, new FeedBackArguments{FeedbackString = message, FeedbackDate = DateTime. public void InvokeResult(bool passed, string resultMessage, string test) {

        if (SendResult != null)
            SendResult(this, new ResultArguments { Resultstring = resultMessage, Passed = passed, PassedTime = DateTime.Now, Teststring = test});

    }
}
```

this is my module:

```
[Export(typeof(IModule))]
    public class Tests : BaseModule, IModule
    {
     public void RememberDescription()
        {
            InvokeResult(true, "Please remember to upload a description","Rememberdescription");
        }
```

And I would like to import the module like this:

```
[Import(typeof(IModule))]

public IModule MEF;
  public void RunTests(string list)
    {

            AggregateCatalog catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
            catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(folderlocator));

            try
            {
                CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
                container.ComposeParts(this);



                MEF.SendResult += MEF_SendResult;



            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

            }
        }

    }

    void MEF_SendFeedBack(object sender, FeedBackArguments e)
    {

    }

    void MEF_SendResult(object sender, ResultArguments e)
    {

    }
```

The event gets triggered in the module itself, but for some reason the event doesn't get fired or the listener doesn't work as it should. Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: There is something wrong with the code you posted (format or something; not all the code is showing up, at least that wat you intend to be there). Please fix it then I'll have a look again.

Comment: Hello @FrancoisNel, That is correct I edited the code which had nothing to do with this problem out. As for the voids MEF_SendFeedBack(){} and MEF_SendResult().... Those are not filled yet, because they never get "invoked" as there is something wrong with the events, never seem to be triggered

Comment: Look at your first code block. There are 2 if-statements that follow each other which does not make sense. But let me ask this: you stated "events get triggered in the module itself", but how (by what) and when does it get triggered? Does it not get triggered before the event handler is hooked?

Comment: @Stephen Where is the call to RememberDescription and where is the implementation of InvokeResult? Also why BaseModule does not implement IModule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal events won't work in MEF, I used the Event Aggregator instead which worked for me